# Dismissing a UITabBarVC and returning to the sign in screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a sign in VC that pushes a sign up VC; both are under a Navigation Controller. From the sign up VC I call modaling a UITabBar VC with the whole application content.  Inside the UITabBar VC I have another VC with a Sign Out method. My question is: how is the correct way to go back to Sign In VC? In this scenario, if I dismiss the UITabBar VC I return to the sign up VC.

I have drawn a diagram that describes the scenario:
[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Marcos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the state of the `UINavigationController` which is presenting the modal view before dismissing it. For instance calling

```
[(UINavigationController *)self.presentingViewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO]
```

from the modal view controller, will result in your underlying `UINavigationController` to get back to its root view controller, which - in your specific scenario - will be the Sign In VC, so when you dismiss the modal view, the underlying view controller will be whatever you desire.